# Calculate the difference between dates in two data frames

Tags: r, dataframe

The below is the first data frame

```
Account reference number    Amount  Date
A   1   1583.51 16/05/2016
B   2   4038.18 27/09/2016
C   3   1161.36 20/05/2016
C   4   732.39  24/10/2016
C   5   747.69  24/11/2016
```

The below is second data frame

```
Account reference number    Amount  Date
A   6   3062.88 03/05/2016
A   7   2619.09 03/05/2016
A   8   4743.22 09/05/2016
B   9   115.28  03/05/2016
B   10  993.14  03/05/2016
B   11  879.05  03/05/2016
C   12  50.93   03/05/2016
C   13  21.83   03/05/2016
C   14  14.55   03/05/2016
```

I want to find the date difference for each account by comparing two data frames.
For example, if you compare the dates in data frames for account 'A' it should be -13 days as start date would be 16/05/2016 and the stop date would be 03/05/2016.

I want the date in first data frame to be checked with every date in second data frame for that account. For example, 16/05/2016 should check with 03/05/2016 and 09/05/2016.

Comment: did you try merging and subtracting?

Comment: What happens in the case of `Account C`? You have 3 dates in first data frame and 3 dates in second data frame...is that 9 total comparisons?

Comment: Would you provide your desired output?

Comment: Thanks Masoud. Please see the below output.
A 1 -13 days
A 7 -13 days
A 8 -7 days
B 9 -147 days
B 10 -147 days
B 11 -147 days

Comment: so `reference number` column does not matter at all?

Comment: If you edit your question and provide a table (like what you have for your datasets) for your desired output, we can help you. Otherwise, it is a bit hard to guess what's exactly in your mind. Let us know when you had that updated in your question.

Comment: @user8320197 looks like you received a lot of answers below. If any of them solved your issue please consider accepting it as an answer by clicking on the check mark to the left. This lets the community know the answer helped you to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Created my own sample data, since yours is hard to copy. A solution based on dplyr:

```
df1 = data.frame(account=c(1,2,3,4),date=seq(Sys.Date(),Sys.Date()+3,by=1),value = c(1,1,1,1))
df2 = data.frame(account=c(1,2,3,4),date=seq(Sys.Date()+2,Sys.Date()+5,by=1), value = c(2,2,2,2))

require(dplyr)

df2 = df2 %>% select(account,df2.date=date)
df1 = df1 %>% left_join(df2) %>% mutate(diff = as.numeric(date-df2.date))
```

INPUT

```
> df1
  account       date value
1       1 2017-07-17     1
2       2 2017-07-18     1
3       3 2017-07-19     1
4       4 2017-07-20     1
> df2
  account       date value
1       1 2017-07-19     2
2       2 2017-07-20     2
3       3 2017-07-21     2
4       4 2017-07-22     2
```

OUTPUT

```
> df1
  account       date value   df2.date diff
1       1 2017-07-17     1 2017-07-19   -2
2       2 2017-07-18     1 2017-07-20   -2
3       3 2017-07-19     1 2017-07-21   -2
4       4 2017-07-20     1 2017-07-22   -2
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity I suppose that the first date frame is called a and the second b.
I've created them in an abbreviated form

```
a <- data.frame(Account = c("A,B"), reference_number = c(1,2), Amount = c(1583.51,4038.18),  Date = c("16/05/2016","27/09/2016"))
b <- data.frame(Account = c("A,A"), reference_number = c(6,7), Amount = c(3062.88,2619.09),  Date = c("03/05/2016","03/05/2016"))
```

You can find differences between 2 dates in this way:

```
#days
difftime(strptime(b$Date[1], format = "%d/%m/%Y"),
     strptime(a$Date[1], format = "%d/%m/%Y"),units="days")

#weeks
difftime(strptime(b$Date[1], format = "%d/%m/%Y"),
     strptime(a$Date[1], format = "%d/%m/%Y"),units="weeks")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sample data based on `Florian`'s answer:

```
df1 = data.frame(account=c("A","A","B","B"),date=seq(Sys.Date(),Sys.Date()+3,by=1),value = c(1,1,1,1))
df2 = data.frame(account=c("A","A","A","B"),date=seq(Sys.Date()+2,Sys.Date()+5,by=1),value = c(2,2,2,2))
```

I added in several instances of each `account` in each data frame. This is important for obtaining correct output for your own data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
full_join(df1,df2,by="account") %>%
  mutate(diff=date.x-date.y) %>%

  account     date.x value.x     date.y value.y    diff
1       A 2017-07-17       1 2017-07-19       2 -2 days
2       A 2017-07-17       1 2017-07-20       2 -3 days
3       A 2017-07-17       1 2017-07-21       2 -4 days
4       A 2017-07-18       1 2017-07-19       2 -1 days
5       A 2017-07-18       1 2017-07-20       2 -2 days
6       A 2017-07-18       1 2017-07-21       2 -3 days
7       B 2017-07-19       1 2017-07-22       2 -3 days
8       B 2017-07-20       1 2017-07-22       2 -2 days
```

Comment: Thank you very much but I want the date in first data frame to be checked with every date in second data frame for that account. if you take account A in my question 16/05/2016 should check with 03/05/2016 and 09/05/2016

Comment: Oh, I see. It wasn't clear from your original post. (You should update your post to indicate this...) That complicates things. What happens in the case of `Account C`? You have 3 dates in first data frame and 3 dates in second data frame...is that 9 total comparisons?

Comment: In the case of Account C, 20/05/2016 should check with 03/05/2016 three times, 24/10/2016 should check with 03/05/2016 three times and 24/11/2016 should check with 03/05/2016 three times as we have same date for the three transactions

Comment: Can we do using a for or nested for loop?